# Generic type inference

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I'm pretty comfortable with generics but being a person that likes to understand every detail I have this question. In my implementation of the `Where` LINQ extension method

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(
                         this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
        {
            foreach (T element in source)
                if (predicate(element))
                    yield return element;
        }
    }
```

why is the `T` in `Where<T>` necessary? Why can't the type be inferred from the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>`? In other words, why can't the signature be

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it can, but it is there for cases where it cannot. You can use `Where` without supplying `T` in most cases.

Comment: @JonathanWood: He is talking about the declaration signature, not the invocation.

Comment: Well, in order to ever be able to supply `T` in any case, it would need to be in the declaration. What did I miss?

Comment: Your second declaration is legal C# when there is an existing type named `T` in scope. It declares an extension method on the type `IEnumerable<T>`. You must specific the generic type parameter to distinguish these two cases.

Comment: @mike That makes sense but maybe not in this particular case, being that extension methods have to be in a non-generic class. Right? Could you provide an example of your suggestion?

Comment: @Mark For example, if you declare `public class T { }` what would you have the compiler do? Does your method suddenly become non-generic because in another file someone declared a type called `T`?

Comment: @mike Please bear with me I'm getting there. I see your point but this raises a sub-question for me. Declaring `public class T {}` makes `public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)` valid, and I understand why. But now I'm curious as to the strict definition of Generic. Is this version regarded as a Generic method?

Comment: @Mark No, your new version does not declare a generic method. It is a normal method that has formal parameter and return types that are closed generic types (e.g. `IEnumerable<T>`, in this case `T` is an actual type) but the method itself is not generic. A generic method has one or more type parameters for which type arguments must specified (or inferred) when it is called. Declaring it as `Where<T>` says this is a generic method with a single type parameter and that type will be represented by the placeholder `T`.

Answer (score 4):

> `public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)`

With such a signature, `T` would be an undeclared identifier. You cannot just use an `IEnumerable<T>` if `T` is not defined anywhere. Therefore, you need a generic parameter `T` on the method (or alternatively on the class) level for `IEnumerable<T>` to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason at all that the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` and `Where<T>` have to be the same thing; you are saying they must be by specifying them both as `T`

`IEnumerable<T>` is what is being returned by the method. `Where<T>` is for defining what the generic type used as the parameters is. It is conceivably possible those `T` could be different types, if you had not specified them both as `T`

That is: The return type (`IEnumerable<T>`) is not necessarily related to the types of the parameters (the `T` in the `Where<T>`).

Answer (score 1):

The `<T>` prefacing the argument list is acting a bit like a "variable declaration" - like you can't just say:

```
x = 10;
```

You need to declare that variable first:

```
int x = 10;
```

It's just here it's a variable declaration for a `Type`.

Now *usage*, that's another thing altogether - the compiler will do it damnedest to try to infer what "values" to stick in each one of those `Type` variables, based on usage and existing signatures, but those signatures still have to be declared.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing *definition* of the `Where<T>` method and *usage* of it.

When *defining* (and declaring) the function, you need the type parameter there to show the compiler that the method is generic. When you've declared the type parameter `T`, you can use it to show what types the input and output arguments have (in this case the `IEnumerable<T>`).

When *using* the method, you don't need to specity it - it can very well be inferred from the first input argument. Try the following if you're unsure:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var odds = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 != 0);

// test for example odds is IEnumerable<int> if you want confirmation =)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static T Bar<T>(T input) { return input; }
}
```

Normally the type would be inferred.

```
Foo.Bar("test");
```

But what happens in this case?

```
Foo.Bar(null); //error
```

Type arguments cannot be inferred and if this was at compile time you'd get a compilation error.

```
Foo.Bar<string>(null); //works
```